# Applying math.ceil to an array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, ceil

What is the proper way to apply math.ceil to an entire array? See the following Python code:

```
    index = np.zeros(len(any_array))
    index2 = [random.random() for x in xrange(len(any_array))
    ##indexfinal=math.ceil(index2)  <-?
```

And I want to return the ceiling value of every element within the array. Documentation states that math.ceil returns the ceiling for any input x, but what is the best method of applying this ceiling function to every element contained within the array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `numpy.ceil()` function instead. The Numpy package offers vectorized versions of most of the standard math functions.

```
In [29]: import numpy as np
In [30]: a = np.arange(2, 3, 0.1)
In [31]: a
Out[31]: array([ 2. ,  2.1,  2.2,  2.3,  2.4,  2.5,  2.6,  2.7,  2.8,  2.9])

In [32]: np.ceil(a)
Out[32]: array([ 2.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.])
```

This technique should work on arbitrary `ndarray` objects:

```
In [53]: a2 = np.indices((3,3)) * 0.9

In [54]: a2
Out[54]:
array([[[ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
        [ 0.9,  0.9,  0.9],
        [ 1.8,  1.8,  1.8]],

       [[ 0. ,  0.9,  1.8],
        [ 0. ,  0.9,  1.8],
        [ 0. ,  0.9,  1.8]]])

In [55]: np.ceil(a2)
Out[55]:
array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 2.,  2.,  2.]],

       [[ 0.,  1.,  2.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  2.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  2.]]])
```

Comment: Thank  you. I was not aware of this numpy function. This is the type of answer I was looking for, although some other answerers have also provided excellent answers more specified to my question.

Comment: Glad I successfully divined the true intent of your question!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) function in python which takes a method as first argument and an iterable as second argument and returns a iterable with the given method applied at each element.

```
import math

arr = [1.2, 5.6, 8.0, 9.4, 48.6, 5.3]

arr_ceil = map(math.ceil, arr)

print arr_ceil

>>> [2.0, 6.0, 8.0, 10.0, 49.0, 6.0]
```

Comment: @holdenweb, The OP specifically mentioned **math.ceil()** that's why I used the given method, I know `numpy` methods are far more efficient, But just meeting the requirements of the question.

Comment: Numpy offers specific functions to operate on whole ndarrays. I was rather disappointed to find out that this actually operates quicker than the numpy `ceil` function! This is probably because it returns a `map` object and not an `ndarray`. Just because the OP asked about math.ceil doesn't necessarily mean that's the answer they need

Comment: I just tried to timeit map(math.ceil, x) and [math.ceil(p) for p in x]. Interestingly map version is faster. Any ideas why? of course np.ceil is fastest

Comment: It's probably because the comprehension is iterating in Python whereas the `map()` method is iterating in C.

Comment: This is a great method in addition to np.ceil. Thank you for responding. Its always helpful to have more than one way to write an operation.